# IE 8 Pull Down Menu is not working in IE10

Tags: asp.net, css, aspmenu-control

I have pull down menu which is working fine in IE8 without any issues but not working in IE 10. Not even able to click the menu in IE10. Also I checked in IE 10 compatibility mode, but still not working. Below is the code I have written and loading the menu items dynamically.

```html
<div class="clear hideSkiplink" style="background-image: url(Images/horizBar1.jpg);padding-top: 10px">
  <asp:Menu ID="menuMain" runat="server" StaticMenuItemStyle-CssClass="menuItem" 
            DynamicMenuItemStyle-CssClass="menuItem" EnableViewState="false" 
            IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal" 
            OnMenuItemClick="menuMain_MenuItemClick" BackColor="#FFFFFF" 
            BorderColor="#296573" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Verdana" 
            Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="#296573">
    <StaticMenuItemStyle CssClass="menuItem"></StaticMenuItemStyle>
    <DynamicMenuItemStyle CssClass="menuItem"></DynamicMenuItemStyle>
  </asp:Menu>
</div>
```

style:

```css
.menuItem {
  border: groove 1px black;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 2px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  background-color: Transparent; 
  font-family: verdana; 
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Could you please show a live link or at least the resulting html of your page?

Comment: I am not able to upload the page. Actually the issue is mouse hover is not working and not able to click on the menu. But the menu is getting displayed properly.